# How to store query result into temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert the results generated from SQL query into temporary table using following query:

```
SELECT * 
INTO #YourTempTable
FROM
    (WITH cte AS 
     (
        SELECT
            sb.case, sb.Trace, sb.Amount, sp.edge, sp.UserId,
            count(*) over (partition by sp.edge) as cnt
        FROM 
            Budget sb 
        JOIN
            Sap sp ON sb.Trace = sp.Trace
        WHERE 
            sb.Trace IN (SELECT Trace FROM Sap 
                         WHERE sb.UserId in ('R5', 'HB'))
     )
     SELECT cte.*
     FROM cte
     WHERE cnt > 1
     ORDER BY edge DESC;
)
```

I'm getting error:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.
>
> Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Can anyone please let me know about this?

Answer (score 7):

`WITH` goes before `SELECT`:

```
with cte as (
      select sb.case, sb.Trace, sb.Amount, sp.edge, sp.UserId,
             count(*) over (partition by sp.edge) as cnt
      from Budget sb join
           Sap sp 
           on sb.Trace = sp.Trace
      where sb.Trace in (select Trace from Sap where sb.UserId in ('R5', 'HB'))
     )
SELECT * 
INTO #YourTempTable
FROM cte
WHERE cnt > 1
ORDER BY edge desc;
```

As a note:  your syntax *is* supported by Oracle, but not by other databases.  In general, the `WITH` should be at the very beginning of the statement.

Also, the subquery is unnecessary.  In fact, you would get two additional errors:  the subquery has no alias and `ORDER BY` is not allowed in subqueries (unless `TOP` or `FETCH FIRST` is used).

Comment: Faster response, and you found more broken stuff than me.  Gets my upvote.

Comment: Does it creates a temporary table into DB? Or is the table just created on fly?

Comment: @user2961127 . . . SQL Server doesn't materialize CTEs (for better or worse).  The logic is just incorporated into the execution plan.